# How can I launch clion shortly using commandline?

Tags: ubuntu, command-line, clion

I downloaded clion and made desktop entry, but I don't know how to launch clion on commandline. As we can launch sublime-text by typing `subl` on commandline, how can I make shortcut for clion using commandline?

Answer (score 2):

Three most obvious possibilities:

1. Create a symlink from clion.sh to somewhere in your PATH
2. Add the bin/ directory to Your PATH
3. Write a shellscript yourself to launch Clion.
   ....